# Change SQLEXPRESS instance name

Tags: sql-server-2008

I installed VS2010 and it automatically installed SQL Server 2008 Express.

Now, the installed instance is called SQLEXPRESS, therefore to connect to it I have to use 'localhost\SQLEXPRESS' or '.\SQLEXPRESS' or something like that.

I want to rename the instance so I can connect using only my computer name or 'localhost'.

How do I do this?

Thanks

Comment: To add to the above description. By default, SQL Server uses localhost as name while SQLExpress uses localdb as name

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no way you can rename an instance of SQL Server. You can probably create a new instance with just the machine name so that it suits you requirements.

I'm not sure of the express version of SQL Server bundled with VS 2010, but with the Standalone SQL Express 2008 (or R2), running the setup again will let you create a new instance.

[image]

Comment: +1 You will need to re run the setup (this will create a new instance of SQL Server) and make sure that you select the Default Instance. This will allow you to connect without specifying any name or juts a '.'

Comment: Thanks, I ended up uninstalling the previous version and installing it again.

Answer (score 6):

I was always under the very strong impression (I am only questioning it a little for the first time due to the conflicts in the link below) that you can only do that by reinstalling SQL (I have always had to create additional instances with an additional install anyway), and choosing a new instance name. I found the link below on a Microsoft SQL Server forum that has a very divided opinion. I side with the Microsoft MVP moderator, because I think that the attempted change only changes the server name though.

I would follow the advice of detaching the databases, reinstall SQL with the new instance name, and then reattach. That is guaranteed to work.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlexpress/thread/9541a5b7-658d-42b1-85ee-110ba61aa28a/

Answer (score 5):

I followed this procedure :::

**For default instance**

```
sp_dropserver 'old_name'
go
sp_addserver 'new_name','local'
go
```

**For named instance**

```
sp_dropserver 'Server Name\old_Instance_name'
go
sp_addserver 'ServerName\New Instance Name','local'
go
```

and then **restarted the SQL server**.

Now I'm able to connect to both default instance and SQLExpress

Comment: This does not work for SQL Server Express 2016. It just has no effect. SQL keeps being available only via "MACHINE\SQLEXPRESS".

Comment: It worked for me in 2008. I never tried in 2016.

Comment: Works fine in MSSQL Server 2019, on Ubuntu.

Comment: Link is now malicious - redacted